# Is there an official source on all Outlook message properties when parsing a .msg file?

Tags: outlook, msg

I'm parsing a .msg file (using Apache POI), but I have trouble finding any official or published list of properties supported by Outlook. The best I could find are list used by few other projects that claim to have gotten some of it from a *mapitags.h* file.

Examples:

- https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl/blob/master/lib/Email/Outlook/Message/Base.pm
- https://github.com/JoshData/convert-outlook-msg-file/blob/master/outlookmsgfile.py (which got it from
  https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl/blob/master/mapitags.h)

For example, what is property 6001?

After looking around, I found Microsoft's published [Mapitags.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/commonly-used-header-files) (download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12905)), it is mentioned as:

> "6000 65FF    User-defined non-transmittable property"

So is there no way of finding out what this property does? I'm looking for a bounceTo property, but it's not mentioned in any of these header files.

Comment: Do you know if the header files download is still officially available? The download links are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such list. Besides hundreds or even thousands of properties used by Outlook itself, store provides and third-party apps are free to use their own properties.
See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/utils.htm#xmapi for a short overview of the MAPI properties.

If you want to see properties set on an existing message or MSG file, use [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author).